# display camera view as bagckground image

Tags: android, background, camera, surfaceview

I'd like to use camera's preview image as background image for a SurfaceView's canvas.
How it can be done?
Thanks,
Eyal.

Comment: have you tried coding anything yet?

Comment: Not yet. I'll may do it later.

Comment: here is what I tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239623/how-to-use-camera-in-a-customized-cclayer-cocos2d-for-android, but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked for me :
I created a relative layout in the XML, Then i created a customCameraView and added it to to the layout, Then i created the GLSurfaceView, made the background translucent and set its setZOrderOnTop to true, then added it to the layout.

Comment: I wrote it 1 year back
I'll post it if I find the project

Comment: Don't worry i have solved the issue :). Thanks for your help. really appreciate it!!